# Post migration issues (SQL Server 2008 to 2016)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2016

We've migrated a SQL Serer 2008 database (which is now offline and have no access to it) to SQL Server 2016. This error started to occur

> Error 51001, severity 16, state 1 was raised, but no message with that error number was found in sys.messages. If error is larger than 50000, make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage.

and so I don't know if the original DBA or developers added custom messages in the old version or not. Was the '2008' version "forgiving" in the sense that if custom errors were stored in user-defined table instead of sys.messages and up on exception this table was queried and custom message used. I hope I making myself clear.

Here the code, error occurs on kine with this code

```
SET @XML = (SELECT [dbo].[fn_BuildXMLBody](@XML, @sErrMsg, @ID,'5100100401001'))



CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ESI_AddLanguageTypeDev]
@vLang      VARCHAR(2)  --Required Parameter

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE 
@iRetVal    INT,
@sProcName  VARCHAR(100),
@sErrMsg    VARCHAR(500),
@iCount INT,
@vErr       VARCHAR(5)  --Indicates if errors have occurred.

DECLARE 
@XML        varchar(7960),  
@XMLHeader  VARCHAR(20),
@XMLFooter  VARCHAR(20),
@ID     int

DECLARE @intEq_ID INT 

SET @XMLHeader = (SELECT [dbo].[fn_BuildXMLHeader]())
SET @ID = '51001'
SET @sProcName = 'sp_ESI_AddLanguageType'

SET @vErr = 'False'
SET @vLang = RTRIM(LTRIM(@vLang))

IF exists (SELECT Lang
        FROM    dbo.Language
        WHERE Lang = @vLang)
    BEGIN
        SET @vErr = 'True'
        SET @sErrMsg = (SELECT [dbo].[fn_GetValidationErrorMessage]('5100100401001'))   
        SET @XML = (SELECT [dbo].[fn_BuildXMLBody](@XML, @sErrMsg, @ID,'5100100401001'))
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.Language(
                Lang )
        VALUES(@vLang)

        SELECT @intEq_ID = (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Language'))

        IF @@ERROR <> 0 
            BEGIN
                SET @vErr = 'True'
                SET @sErrMsg = (SELECT [dbo].[fn_GetValidationErrorMessage]('5100100404001'))   
                SET @XML = (SELECT [dbo].[fn_BuildXMLBody](@XML, @sErrMsg, @ID,'5100100404001'))
            END
    END

IF @vErr = 'True'
    BEGIN
        SET @XMLFooter = (SELECT [dbo].[fn_BuildXMLFooter]())   
        SET @XML = (@XMLHeader + @XML + @XMLFooter)
        -- output the xml as a single parameter
        SELECT @XML = LTRIM(RTRIM(@XML))
        --RAISERROR @ID @XML
        RAISERROR (@ID,
        16, 1, @XML);
        RETURN -1
    END
ELSE    
    BEGIN
        SELECT @intEq_ID as RETURN_CODE
        RETURN @intEq_ID
        RETURN 0
    END
 END
 GO
```

Comment: Do you need to retrieve the actual custom error message from 2008? Why not just add a new one with sp_addmessage?

Comment: We can do that, I was just wondering if there was a system change in SQL2016 that caused this to be suddenly an issue. We have no reports of this being a problem in '2008'.

Comment: @Risho There has been no change in this functionality. It worked in the old system because someone added the messages to the server instance - which your migration process did not do.